# Django OperationalError: could not fork new process for connection

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, out-of-memory

I've started getting this error on the production environment this morning, after getting Django-storages, Boto, and Django-compressor working to put static files on S3 yesterday, though I don't know if that is related...

```
OperationalError: could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory

could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory


Stacktrace (most recent call last):

  File "django/core/handlers/base.py", line 89, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)
  File "reversion/middleware.py", line 17, in process_request
    if hasattr(request, "user") and request.user.is_authenticated():
  File "django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "django/utils/functional.py", line 248, in _setup
    self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()
  File "django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 16, in <lambda>
    request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
  File "django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 8, in get_user
    request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
  File "django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 98, in get_user
    user_id = request.session[SESSION_KEY]
  File "django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 39, in __getitem__
    return self._session[key]
  File "django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 165, in _get_session
    self._session_cache = self.load()
  File "django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 19, in load
    expire_date__gt=timezone.now()
  File "django/db/models/manager.py", line 131, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 361, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 85, in __len__
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 291, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 763, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 817, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 308, in cursor
    cursor = util.CursorWrapper(self._cursor(), self)
  File "django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 177, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "psycopg2/__init__.py", line 178, in connect
    return _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
```

I am deploying the site on Heroku. It works for a bit after I restart the application, but stops working again after a few minutes.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Comment: You have DB connection problems (obl). Google gove me this link http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/opsbfuzdnnuo8gh7@developer3 So better will be if you contact with Heroku tech support.

Comment: @b1 Ahh, thanks, I somehow solved it a while ago, but forgot to update the answer and don't remember how I solved it anymore!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same problem trying to set up a simple django web application with a postgresql database on heroku and managed to solve it.

I don't fully understand the error but the fix is fairly simple: when you are passing python lists created by queries to your database, you need to ***limit the size of the list***.

So for example if you are passing as context the following list:

`set_list = userSetTable.objects.all()`

`return render(request, 'fc/user.html', {'set_list': set_list,})`

That will cause an error because set_list might be really big.  You need to specify a maximum size:

```
set_list = userSetTable.objects.all()[0:20]
```

So in a real-world application, you might want to display the list as page results or whatever... you get the point.