# Postgres process fork error on Heroku dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm currently having an issue with my Heroku RoR app which results in it not being able to communicate with the Postgres database. Upon trying to load my app, I get the generic "something went wrong" issue.

Running `heroku logs` returns the following:

```
2013-03-28T03:46:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-03-28T03:46:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-03-28T03:46:01+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-28 03:46:01] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-03-28T03:46:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2013-03-28T03:46:05+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-03-28T03:46:05+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-03-28T03:46:07+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/projects" for 0.0.0.0 at 2013-03-28 03:48:19 +0000
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::Error (could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]: could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `initialize'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]: could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `new'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:326:in `initialize'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `connect'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3713961688065884330__call__3295828753336647570__callbacks'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

The key part being at the beginning:

```
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::Error (could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]: could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-28T03:48:19+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014138/django-operationalerror-could-not-fork-new-process-for-connection) question, and I tried to limit the amount of returned items, but that doesn't appear to be the issue. I only have two items in my database, both of which have the following model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :image, :name, :url
end
```

Which are text/string fields.

Comment: I find it weird that your stack trace contains this line `/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in 'select'` I was under the impression Heroku only ran Thin servers

Comment: @LeoCorrea see this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby#webserver

Comment: Ah, I see. I've been using Thin for too long.

Comment: @LeoCorrea yeah, this is just something I'm testing with and tossed up just yesterday. It appears as though this is an issue on Heroku's end, rather than something wrong with my app though (see Lucas's response down)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed you posted this roughly 15 mins ago. I have started seeing this error in the last half hour on heroku too (connecting to the dev/free postgres db). I wonder if it's a problem at their end? Their status page doesn't give any hints.

Comment: It very well may be. I've been experiencing this problem throughout the day off and on, so I thought it may be something with them. Glad to see I'm not the only one having this issue.

Comment: I'm getting a slightly more encouraging error now: "FATAL:  the database system is starting up (PG::Error)"

Comment: For the last 15 minutes they've had the same issue

Comment: It happened to us today. Unfortunately given the limited control over DB given by Heroku there was nothing we could do. Is there a way to restart DB?

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know, the key part of this error is:

```
could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
```

This suggests that the host, container, or ulimit context has no more available memory. Creating a new process requires allocating memory for the stack and various other basic data structures. It isn't much memory, so the inability to fork a process suggests that you're totally out of RAM.

On a normal host you would log in (if you could), examine the running processes, kill problematic processes, set memory limits on problem services, etc. This isn't really an option on Heroku, but you *can*:

- Reduce the number of concurrent connections you are using; and
- Reduce `work_mem` and `maintenance_work_mem` for each connection

If you're exceeding the RAM available in your container this will help. If the whole host is out of memory it won't do you any good.

I did some emergency support for a customer who had a similar problem after they *upgraded* to a bigger Heroku plan. We never got a solid answer as to what happened, but the customer was eventually - after several tries and a couple of days - to create a follower (replica) of their database and then fail over to it. This resolved the issues, suggesting that the problems may have been to do with the container that was hosting that database instance. If you can successfully create a follower, try this. You may have to reduce your connection counts and `work_mem` etc to be able to do this.

In general, please consider that PostgreSQL will perform best with relatively low numbers of actively working connections and a good connection pool. You'll typically get better throughput with 20 or 30 pooled connections than you will with 200 or 300 and no pooler. Reduce your connection counts until the problem goes away and you'll probably see performance increase too.

(Disclosure: I work for 2ndQuadrant, another PostgreSQL support and services company).

Comment: This is actually a very small testing app with very few concurrent connections, and as I had said in the original post, I only had two small records and therefore couldn't figure out why I'd run out of memory. I've determined that it's just an issue on Heroku's end, and not necessarily with my app. You did give some very good information for future reference though, so thank you.

Comment: @CraigRinger, could you detail how to actually reduce the number of connections on Heroku? Where do you set these variables? Thanks!

Comment: @ben You control connection counts in your application, not the database config. Reduce the number of connections your app uses. For the case of Rails apps that's done by setting a smaller pool size in `database.yml`.

Comment: @CraigRinger but Heroku rewrites database.yml?

Comment: @ben Ah, in that case ... no idea, I don't use Heroku myself and only know the PostgreSQL side of things well. Post a new question tagged [tag:heroku] [tag:ruby-on-rails]