# PostgreSQL 9.3 main could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm performing multiple PostgreSQL updates in real time: ~50 writes per second.

- Ubuntu 14.04
- PostgreSQL 9.3 main
- 4GB RAM

This is the code I'm using to write in Database, I'm closing connection everytime after writing to database:

```
def update_database(sqlquery):
    """

    :rtype : object
    :param sqlquery:
    :return:
    """
    try:
        db = DatabaseSession.DatabaseSession(settings.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
        db.execute(sqlquery)
    except psycopg2.ProgrammingError, exception:
        print exception
    except Exception, exception:
        print exception
```

Database session:

```
class DatabaseSession(object):
    """

    """

    def __init__(self, db_url):
        """

        :param db_url:
        :return:
        """
        self.db_url = db_url
        self.session = None
        self.engine = None

    def get_session(self):
        """

        :return:
        """
        try:
            self.engine = create_engine(self.db_url,
                                        pool_recycle=settings.SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE,
                                        pool_size=settings.SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE,
                                        max_overflow=settings.SQLALCHEMY_MAX_OVERFLOW)
            Session = sessionmaker()
            Session.configure(bind=self.engine)
            self.session = Session()
            self.session._model_changes = {}
            return self.session
        except Exception, e:
            log.error('DatabaseSession() get_session(): ' + str(e.message))

    def execute(self, sqlcommand):
        """

        :param sqlcommand:
        :return:
        """
        try:
            session_active = False
            connection = None
            # Check if session
            if self.session:
                session_active = True
            else:
                if self.get_session():
                    session_active = True
                else:
                    session_active = False

            if session_active:
                connection = self.engine.connect()
                result = connection.execute(sqlcommand)
                return result
            else:
                log.error('DatabaseSession() Unable to start session. Session is not active')

        except psycopg2.OperationalError as exception:
            log.exception('DatabaseSession() OperationalError(): {}'.format(exception))
        except Exception as exception:
            log.exception('DatabaseSession() Execute(): '.format(exception))
        finally:
            if connection:
                connection.close()
```

Settings:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "postgresql://" + dbusername + ":" + dbpassword + "@" + dbhost + "/" + dbname
SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = False
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE = 1000
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT = 5
SQLALCHEMY_MAX_OVERFLOW = 100
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE = 60
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
DATABASE_CONNECT_OPTIONS = None
SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN = True
```

After few minutes I get this:

```
[2016-07-21 03:23:44,581: ERROR/Worker-7] DatabaseSession() Execute(): 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/telephonist/api/version1_0/database/DatabaseSession.py", line 65, in execute
    connection = self.engine.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2018, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 72, in __init__
    if connection is not None else engine.raw_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2104, in raw_connection
    self.pool.unique_connection, _connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2078, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1405, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 202, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2074, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 318, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 713, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 480, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1060, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1057, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 323, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 449, in __init__
    self.connection = self.__connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 607, in __connect
    connection = self.__pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 97, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 385, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory

could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
```

I have adjusted my database settings:

```
max_connections = 1024                  # (change requires restart)
shared_buffers = 512MB                  # min 128kB
                                        # (change requires restart)
temp_buffers = 8MB                      # min 800kB
work_mem = 1MB                          # min 64kB
```

Related posts:

[Heroku Rails could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149021/heroku-rails-could-not-fork-new-process-for-connection-cannot-allocate-memory)

[Django OperationalError: could not fork new process for connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014138/django-operationalerror-could-not-fork-new-process-for-connection)

Comment: Why are you starting a new connection for every query? Have you considered the possibility that you're simply opening too many connections?